# Will there be any problem arising from changing a double column to numeric?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to alter a column of type double to type numeric in postgres database. My question is, will there be any precautions or issues that I need to take heed of before or after making this change? Thanks for taking the time to answer this question.

Comment: Depending upon the numeric range/precision and values of/in the doubles there could be data loss. (Doubles have more precision at smaller values).

Comment: What if I didn't specify any range/precision when I don't the type conversion i.e I just execute this sql statement :- ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE  numeric. What is the default precision that the database system converts the column into. The table information isn't displaying the precision. What I notice is that, when I did SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name, there were very small difference in terms of floating point, the number is higher when the column was of type double compared to numeric.

Comment: Postgres keeps the data-type through-and-through would be **my guess** (e.g. it doesn't turn the doubles in Numerics internally so there is *the standard IEEE floating-point errors* introduced in the intermediate summation). Postgres *must* honor the Numeric precision when doing math (I think, anyway - 1/3==?). Without specifying a range/precision in NUMERIC it will adapt to store *any* range/precision. See [PostgreSQL Numeric](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) -- this also means that doubles may be/are faster, fsvo "faster".

Answer (score 1):

How larege your table ? It will rewrite your whole table, If your table  is so big , it will take so long to excute the "Alter commond", so it's painfull to your application ! Hope this will help you .